# How to integrate NPlot in MonoDevelop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, monodevelop

NPlot is a charting library which could be used in GTK#. I've downloaded its [tarball](http://netcontrols.org/nplot/wiki/index.php?n=Main.DownloadArea) here.

The README file contains this:

> The first version of NPlot-Gtk was made by Miguel de Icaza, and was  a
>   wrapper of NPlot 0.9.8.5.
>
> Now the wrapper of version 0.9.9.2 has just an NPlot upgrade and  a
>   few hacks over the work of Miguel (Carlos)
>
> ------------------------
>
> This version of NPlot has been extended to support Gtk# on Linux.
>
> The version is based on NPlot 0.9.9.2
>
> To build, type ‘make’
>
> The Gtk# demo is in `lib/mf.exe` and `lib/test.exe`
>
> Notice that you must include in your distirbution not only the `.dll`
>   files, but also the `.config` files.

I'm fairly new to using Linux distros. I do not understand the line from "To build" onwards. I tried adding the `NPlot.dll` to the project I'm making:

[[image: screen shot]

                        <sup>(The above image is a peephole,
and links to the complete version of itself.)</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKLN9.png)

but it keeps throwing `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`:

> Could not load file or assembly 'NPlot, Version=0.9.9.2,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4eda430eb4395eb1' or one of its
>   dependencies.

How should I properly integrate NPlot into MonoDevelop?

---

**Edit 1:** I have now compiled NPlot using the command `make`. But still when I run my program in MonoDevelop, the error is still occurring.

Comment: You "do not understand the line from "To build" onwards."?  Literally?  Try going to the directory where the README file is and typing the command `make`.

Comment: @G-Man Anyway thanks. I've finished doing what you said by the program is still giving the error.

Comment: Well, what happened when you ran `make`?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it more complete.